# (CSS) Second Level Horizontal Menu With Only One Child

Tags: css, menu

I have a menu like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul> 
  <li>item 3</li>
    <ul>
      <li>item-only-child</li>
    </ul>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Second level menu (item) should be displayed horizontally, so I make a rule like

```
.menu li ul { width: 400px }
```

and

```
.menu li li {width: 200px }
```

, the first / wider one, acts as a wrapper. The problem is, when the second level only has 1 child, the wrapper is still there so it creates an empty space because the li only occupy half of the wrapper.

I've tried

```
.menu li ul li:only-child,
```

but it doesn't solve it because I need to change .menu li ul, **if** there is only one li.

I am thinking something like this:

```
**if** .menu li ul li:only-child {
  menu li ul {width: 200px}
}
```

Of course it is not working, just trying to get the point across.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: change "menu" to "ul class="menu".

Comment: Without CSS Selectors Level 4, your best bet is putting a class with `width:200px` in the `ul`s that have a single children manually.

Comment: I thought so.. either that or javascript.

Comment: did u set height for the parent UL ?

Comment: what do you mean by "Second level menu (item) should be displayed horizontally"? and also what empty space is created? your css selectors may be incorrect. You dont have any elements with a class of menu. So you would instead just use 'menu' in your css. ie `menu ul{width:400px;}`. here is a fiddle that may help pinpoint your issue - http://jsfiddle.net/rWDmp/

Comment: Hi, I mean, in most cases (that I've seen) usually the second level menu display vertically one on top of each other. By horizontal, I mean right next to each other, so "item x1" ->(left) "item x2", ->(below) "item x3". So, left to right (2 items) then start again below, instead of item x1 -> (below) item x2 -> (below) item x3. It was a typo, sorry, I was thinking to drive the point by styling .menu li ul and .menu li li with different widths (container and item / li within)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you defined "**.menu**" as a class and not as a selector:
Should be: `menu li li { width: 200px; }` 
// without the point


If you want to work with your existing CSS Code and Class Sample the HTML should be:

```
 <ul class="menu">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2
      <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
      </ul> 
    </li>
  <li>item 3</li>
    <ul>
      <li>item-only-child</li>
    </ul>
  <li>item 4</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Oh yeah there's an error there. Not sure whether that was a typo on OP's part as his code seemingly works for him.

Comment: It was a typo, sorry. I'll fix my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response guys, I appreciate it. Sorry about the confusion regarding the menu / ul class menu, I was thinking to drive the point to the original issue, which I have to change the width of the container for the second level menu if the second level menu only has 1 child / one li.

Anyway, I've resolved it using jQuery. It is for WordPress so either code the walker class or javascript.

Here's the code (just in case someone bumped into the same problem)

```
jQuery(".menu li ul li:only-child").closest('.menu li ul').css('width','200px');
```

So, find a second level menu with only one child (one li), go to the closest selector (parent() is also possible I guess) then set the width.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWDmp/2/) based on lukeocom's